# C scanf program executes 2 times

Tags: c

I'm new to C. I was learning `scanf()` function, and the error that occured is that when I run the .exe file, it executes, gives correct output, and closes; but it then again executes on its own , asks for input and gives correct output and closes. Here's my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a;
    printf("Enter a num\n");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    int b = 1601;
    if (a == b) {
        printf("Found a match!!");
    } else {
        printf("Match not found!");
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: In the code, there is only one mistake. You ignore what `scanf()` returns. You should write `if ((scanf("%d", &a) == 1) && (a == b))` instead of `if (a == b)`. Other than that, there is no reason for the described behavior, at least not a problem with the code. Can you please give more details about your environment and how are you testing the *.exe* file?

Comment: What input are you providing when you run the program the first time?

Comment: I'm using the MinGW gcc compiler, on Windows XP.

Comment: Mike, I'm typing 10 for the first time

Comment: iharob, your code initiates an endless loop

Comment: This code wouldn't run twice. There must be a problem with how you're running it.

Comment: There is no "\n" at the end of the  2 resulting printf, so the shell prompt must stick to the output and that may sound strange, but it doesn't execute twice. Try `printf("Found/Match...\n");`

Comment: @NamanChhaparia How so? Just replacing that will NOT cause an endless loop. How are you testing it? There has to be something that you are not telling us. Perhaps because you don't think it's relevant. The fix I suggest cannot possible cause that because there are no loops involved.

Comment: @interjay, I'm using it on windows xp, using MinGW gcc compiler. and I'm running it simply through command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

The code works well in Ubuntu 14.04. At MS Windows + MinGW there are some problem sometimes. If you want to develop a program with gcc you should use Unix Like Operating System (Linux, BSD, etc) If you want to still use MS Windows, then you should use MS Visual Studio for the best result.